# How long should Xcode 7 installation take

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I am trying to install Xcode 7 for the fifth time. I always complete the download but the installation does complete. Currently, I've been waiting for over 3 hours for installation and it's still not done.

Comment: You can probably save time by downloading it separately from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ instead of waiting for the system to download it on each attempt. That way if there is an issue, you can try to figure out what happened and then try again without downloading it again for the next try.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32666283/1463604

Answer (score 4):

It's not the installation that is actually taking the most time, but verification of Xcode, once it's downloaded. Like yourself, I was wondering what was going on, but found it best to let it run its course. It would be better if there were some type of progress indicator during the process.

Comment: FYI - You can see the long running progress bar in Launchpad (as opposed to App Store).

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a memory issue, for 4GB ram will take about 3 hours, and for 16GB ram will take about 30 minutes

Answer (score 3):

I was fighting with the same issue for few days, and I found out that none of above answers is complete.

1. Go to developer.apple.com
2. Login
3. Go to downloads (don't click on xcode yet)
4. Go to see all downloads
5. Now navigate to find your desired version of xcode
6. Download .dmg file

Unless you follow those steps you might end like me - being redirected over and over again to the appstore page (and download there was never ending)